# Where clause not filtering properly

Tags: powershell

Using the script below I am trying to filter out applications that don't have a $requirement like Windows 10. When I run this I am still getting returned results with application requirements containing windows 10.

```
 | Where { $_ -notlike 'All_x64_Windows_10_and_higher_Clients' };
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Possible issue with the line above?

```
$warningpreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Get-Content C:\temp\Applications.txt | foreach-object {
$app = Get-CMApplication -Name "$_"; 
[XML]$appXML =$app.SDMPackageXML;
$Requirement = $appXML.AppMgmtDigest.DeploymentType.Requirements.Rule.OperatingSystemExpression.Operands.RuleExpression.RuleID | Where { $_ -notlike 'All_x64_Windows_10_and_higher_Clients' };
If ($Requirement -ne $null -or $Requirement.length -gt 0) {

Write-output "Application Name: $_ | Requirement: $Requirement " 
}
 }
```

Comment: Well, how do property values look like that you'd like to filter out? The condition you have there is the same as using `-ne '...'` as well, so I guess you wanted to use `-notlike` for a reason, but couldn't get the pattern right.

Comment: I would like to just return the apps where they don't have a requirement for Windows10. seems like any filtering I do isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -Like Operator is used for WildCard searches in PowerShell.  So you need an `*` somewhere in your filter.

Try this:

```
 | Where { $_ -notlike "*All_x64_Windows_10_and_higher_Clients*" };
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it is just taking out All_x64_Windows_10_and_higher_Clients from the output and still showing the application that has this requirement

Comment: What are you actually trying to do then?  Your command line says to remove clients like `"*All_x64_Windows_10_and_higher_Clients*"`